# Something that constantly wakes up macOS 10.15.3

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina

I used High Sierra until the Catalina release, bypassing Mojave. On Catalina, I faced a nasty bug that was taking my laptop out of sleep. I tried everything I could.

- Reset SMC, NVRAM
- Turn off Power Nap
- Turn Do Not Disturb on (master switch)
- Created a new user
- Reinstalled macOS

Nothing was helping.

I spent almost two days talking to Apple support, nothing helped.

Here are the logs that show that Wake Requests time coincides with the time that your laptop wakes up from sleep.

```
2020-02-02 19:15:55 +0300 Wake Requests         [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2020-02-02 21:15:55] [*process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=731 wakeAt=2020-02-02 19:28:06 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-seld_alarm,105"]

2020-02-02 19:28:09 +0300 Wake Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to EC.RTC/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%) 119 secs
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you did not mention there are two more settings that you should check: "wake for wifi" and "allow bluetooth to wake up".

Comment: @bdecaf sorry, but it is also disabled